# Start Again Already Running Service?

Tags: android, service, ipc, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver listening called `PACKAGE_ADDED` and an other broadcast receiver listening called `BOOT_COMPLETED`. The `bootcompleted` broadcast receiver starts my service.When the new app is installed, I want to send a message to my service .The first solution that came to my mind was to start the service again with

```
intent.setAction("NEW_APP_INSTALLED"); 
startService(intent);
```

without stopping the service and check the `intent.getAction()` value in the`service.onStart()` method. If the result is `NEW_APP_INSTALLED`, then call `newAppInstalled()`.I don't think this is an elegant solution.

Is starting the service repeatedly a problem? And what happens when my activity binds to it via `ipc(aidl)` while fetching data and the new app installed broadcast receiver starts it again? Lastly what is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: You have a broadcast receiver for BOOT_COMPLETE that starts the service.  Your service could listen for PACKAGE_ADDED.

Answer (score 2):

> Is starting the service again and again problem?
>
> Lastly what is the best way to solve my problem?

It is perfectly fine for you to call `startService` on an already running service. And you can either do it the way you suggested or have two different services (one for boot, one for new_app) or you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the service after it's started, but that wouldn't be effective because then if you try to send a message to it and it's not running already, it won't get the message.. I prefer one service as you suggested and using `startService`.

> And what happens when my activity bind it via ipc (AIDL) fetching data
> and new app installed broadcast receiver starts it again?

Well, I don't know anything about AIDL, really. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) might help. That page does state "Most applications should not use AIDL to create a bound service". This is because it makes multi-threading needed and makes it more complicated.

Please let me know if I failed to answer to your satisfaction - though I can't really elaborate on AIDL specifically because I don't know anything about it.

Comment: So you say starting again a running service is okay .It is not killing service and start again right? it is very important.if its not how it works starting service again and again.The third way you suggest registering broadcast receiver for PACKAGE_ADDED on code way i mean not AndroidManifest might be good solution for me cuz i only want to catch PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast when my service is running so if my service is not running it is not important to catch PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast for me.Any suggestion?

Comment: If you call `startService` while service is running, it just passes  the new intent to the `Service` and calls `onStartCommand`. It does NOT kill the service if you call `startService` on a running service.

Comment: And for catching `PACKAGE_ADDED` you can `registerReceiver(...)` in your service's `onCreate`. I.E. You don't need to have it in your manifest.